# How to locate path to Intel Compilers directory needed to build mpi benchmarks on linux?

Tags: linux, path, directory, intel, icc

I'm new to the command line and linux. I'm trying to build the intel mpi benchmarks i've installed. I can't seem to find the path to Intel Compilers directory in my system. I was told to load the intel module in an interactive job which I did. How can I locate this directory?

I've installed the files for the Intel mpi benchmarks using wget and the link to the github with the files and the next step says to build the benchmarks doing the follow:

```
host$ source <path to Intel Compilers directory>/bin/compilervars.sh 
intel64
host$ source <path to Intel MPI Library directory>/intel64/bin/mpivars.sh
host$ cd <path to Intel MPI Benchmarks directory>/src
host$ make -f make_ict
```

I've used find and locate to search for intel and intel compiler and I get a bunch of results that are of no help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you are on your own machine, and you installed the compilers with default settings, the compilers should be on this path /opt/intel/

However, it seems that you are on some managed cluster when you said you had to load the Intel module in an interactive job. In that case, you the mode of operation highly depends on how your system (and software modules) are designed.

Once the module is loaded, if you type icc on the terminal what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux systems have `locate` installed, which indexes all filenames on the system into a searchable list.  (Usually updated by an `updatedb` cron job overnight that basically runs `find /` and processes the output into a locatedb that any user can search.)

**Use `locate bin/mpivars.sh`** to print all the paths that include `bin/mpivars.sh`.

e.g.  you might find `/opt/icc19/intel64/bin/mpivars.sh`, in which case `/opt/icc19` is the place where the sysadmin installed ICC.